# Two tags for Helicobacter pylori?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

At the moment, Medical Sciences SE has tags [helicobacter-pylori](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/helicobacter-pylori) and [h.-helycobacter-pylori](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/h.-helycobacter-pylori).

Do they refer to the same bacterium? Should they be merged?

Comment: They seem to be the same. Even papers with "helycobacter" in the title seem to use "helico" in the body of the paper.